# Graduation, Privileges, and Deletion

Tags: support, faq-proposed, graduation

Graduation is coming.

Deletion of -1 scored answers is going from a 4,000 reputation privilege to a 20,000 reputation privilege.

Time for some easy cleanup.

Please:

1. Vote on the post
2. Improve if you think it can be saved
3. If it can't be improved:

   - Vote to close (for questions) or vote to delete if closed
   - Vote to delete (for answers)

The following searches will return a bunch of posts. I will group them in to easy bunches so that you can do them in bitesized chunks. Tackling questions first will delete attached answers which may be 一石二鳥 (two birds one stone), so let's tackle those first.

I will do my best to track progress. Due to limitations in the number of flags, we may not be able to vote to delete all members of a group. Such is life. If there are particularly offensive ones, you can always flag in general and have a mod take care of it.

- [29 posts scored -5 or worse](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-7..-5)
- [23 questions scored -4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-4..-4+is%3Aquestion)
- [23 closed questions scored -3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-3..-3+is%3Aquestion)
- [54 closed questions scored -2 that won't be auto-deleted](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-2..-2+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Atrue+answers%3A1..100+duplicate%3Afalse)
- [27 answers scored -4](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-4..-4+is%3Aanswer)
- [20 old answers scored -3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-3..-3+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2010-1-1..2013-1-1)
- [33 answers from 2013 scored -3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-3..-3+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2013-1-1..2013-8-1)
- [27 recent answers scored -3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-3..-3+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2013-8-1..2014-8-1)
- [31 old answers scored -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-2..-2+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2011-1-1..2013-1-1)
- [41 answers from 2013 scored -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-2..-2+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2013-1-1..2013-7-1)
- [64 recent answers scored -2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A-2..-2+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2013-7-1..2014-8-1)

Comment: You can also see posts with delete votes in [The Moderator Tools](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/tools)

Answer (score 8):

I've started to go through some of the most heavily downvoted posts. Posts that were noise or that were not serious, I've removed. However, I encountered cases of heavily downvoted incorrect answers.

In some cases, it's helpful to show incorrect answers as this tells future readers what not to do, especially if there are comments that indicate why the answer is wrong. I haven't deleted these, for this very reason.

When going through posts, ask yourself whats wrong with the post. If it's just that the answer is wrong, we may want to leave them as long as there aren't already a lot of answers. It's a judgement call.

Comment: For those unsure when to delete please see: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/413/delete-votes-and-you

Comment: Yeah I was going to say, I left a fair number of answers with just a downvote rather than casting a delete vote too.